# mouseenter z-index 10 animate to left, then mouseleave z-index -10 animate back to right?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, z-index, mouseenter, mouseleave

I am trying to have this hidden div behind the main div at all times, exept when:

mouse enters the hidden div, it should animate to the left, then back to the right and be on top of the main div

then when mouse leave the hidden div, it animated to the left, and back to the right to be behind the main div.

I'm not familiar with js and jQuery, so I tried something like:

```
<div class="mainDiv">
    content of main div

    <div class="hiddenDiv">
    content of hidden div
    </div>

    rest of content of main div
</div>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".hiddenDiv")css('z-index',"-10");
    //tell hiddenDiv to be hidden, this seem to block everything for some reason

    jQuery(".hiddenDiv").mouseenter(function () {
        jQuery(".hiddenDiv").animate({"left": "-=50px"}, "fast").css('z-index',"10"); 
        //when mouse enters, hiddenDiv shows up
    }),
    jQuery(".hiddenDiv").mouseleave(function () {
        jQuery(".hiddenDiv").animate({"left": "+=50px"}, "slow").css('z-index',"-10"); 
        //when mouse leaves, it's hidden again.
    });
});
</script>
```

But I see that when I give the hidden div a z-index of -10 at the begging, nothing works.
Could anyonde point me to the right direction to ahieve this?

Answer (score 1):

```
 .css('z-index',"10");
```

should be written as

```
 .css('zIndex',"10");
```

and your second statement is wrong, since a dot is missing

```
jQuery(".hiddenDiv").css('zIndex',"-10");
```

so try write like so instead

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var hdiv = jQuery(".hiddenDiv");  /* cache a reference for a matter of performance */

    hdiv.css('zIndex', "-10")
        .mouseenter(function () {
            hdiv.animate({"left": "-=50px"}, "fast")
                .css('zIndex', "10"); 
        })
        .mouseleave(function () {
            hdiv.animate({"left": "+=50px"}, "slow")
                .css('zIndex', "-10"); 
        });
});
```

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work: the -10 z-index prevents the effect/animation/behavior from happening. When I hover the hiddendiv, noting moves and it doesn't show up on top (z-index doesnt change it stays at -10).

Answer (score 1):

First first problem you're having is, your hiddendiv can't be rolled over, its hidden with your -10 z index. Meaning as far as your selector is concerned its not there.

I would change your first selector to:

```
jQuery(".mainDiv").mouseenter(function () {
    //etc etc
```

WIthout this you can not use your hiddenDiv as a selector

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this one;

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  // Hide all .hiddenDiv
  //jQuery(".hiddenDiv").css('z-index',"-10");
  jQuery(".hiddenDiv").hide(); // Maybe this would be enough to hide the elements?

  // Bind events to all .mainDiv
  jQuery('.mainDiv')
    .mouseenter(function () {
      jQuery(this).find('.hiddenDiv') // Find all .hiddenDiv in the current .mainDiv
        //.css('zIndex', "10")
        .show()
        .animate({"left": "-=50px"}, "fast");
    })
    .mouseleave(function () {
      jQuery(this).find('.hiddenDiv')
        .animate({"left": "+=50px"}, "slow", function() {
          // This is a callback function that executes when the animation has finished.
          //jQuery(this).css('zIndex', "-10");
          jQuery(this).hide();
        });
    });
});
```